# How to get a full path of a selected file using <Input Type="file" />

Tags: javascript

Can i get full path of a selected file using javascript like "C:/Users/Username/Downloads". Because i want to pass this path to python script which will perform some operation on selected file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: I just go through this link but it tells, For security reasons browsers do not allow to access the local file system. But i want to know that when we pass the path in src like this <img src="C:/Users/Username/Downloads/Loading.gif"> then how it reads that file from the location as i mentioned in src?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using windows you can go into file explorer and open the folder you want then on the top you can right click on the opened folder and press copy file address as text.

Comment: The asker probably means a file uploaded from a user, so they need a full path on another computer (not their own).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i want to get full path of a selected file at runtime. So that i can pass it to the python script.